# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent ORM randomly returning incorrect relationship - *major update*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel app that powers an ecommerce website with moderate traffic. This website allows people to place orders via the frontend, but it also has backend functionality for taking orders over the phone via a call centre.

An order is related to a customer, and a customer can optionally be a user - a user being someone with a login to the frontend. A customer with no user account is only ever created as a result of an order being taken via the call centre.

The issue I have encountered is very odd, and I believe might be some kind of Laravel bug.

It only occurs very occasionally, but what is happening is that when an order is taken via the call centre for a customer with no user account, an order confirmation is being sent out to a random user - literally random, as far as I can tell, just plucked out of the database despite no relation in the data.

These are the relevant parts of the models in the project:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
}

class Customer extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{ 
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

These are the database migrations for the above (edited for brevity):

```
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->boolean('active');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });

    Schema::create('customers', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable->index();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('telephone')->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });

    Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('payment_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->integer('customer_id')->index();
        $table->integer('staff_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->decimal('total', 10, 2);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

The logic that sends the order confirmation is within an event handler that gets fired after the order has been paid.

Here is the `OrderSuccess` event (edited for brevity):

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;


class OrderSuccess extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $order;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }
}
```

As can be seen, this event is passed an `Order` model object.

Here is the event handler (edited for brevity):

```
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  OrderSuccess  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(OrderSuccess $event)
{
    // set order to paid
    $order = $event->order;
    $order->paid = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $order->save();

    if(!is_null($order->customer->user)) {

        App_log::add('customer_order_success_email_sent', 'Handlers\Events\OrderSuccessProcess\handle', $order->id, print_r($order->customer, true).PHP_EOL.print_r($order->customer->user, true));

        // email the user the order confirmation
        Mail::send('emails.order_success', ['order' => $order], function($message) use ($order)
        {
            $message->to($order->customer->user->email, $order->customer->first_name.' '.$order->customer->last_name)->subject('Order #'.$order->id.' confirmation');
        });
    }

}
```

There is a check to see if the `$order->customer->user` object is not null and, if true, an order confirmation is sent. If it is null (which it frequently is), then no confirmation is sent.

As can be seen from the above, I added a log to record the objects when an email is sent. Here is an example of an erroneous one (again, truncated for brevity):

```
App\Customer Object
(
[attributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10412
        [user_id] => 
        [first_name] => Joe
        [last_name] => Bloggs
        [telephone] => 0123456789
        [created_at] => 2015-09-14 13:09:45
        [updated_at] => 2015-10-24 05:00:01
        [deleted_at] => 
    )

[relations:protected] => Array
    (
        [user] => App\User Object
            (
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1206
                        [email] => johndoe@whoknows.com
                        [password] => hashed
                        [remember_token] => 
                        [created_at] => 2015-09-19 09:47:16
                        [updated_at] => 2015-09-19 09:47:16
                        [deleted_at] => 
                    )
            )

    )

[morphClass:protected] => 
[exists] => 1
[wasRecentlyCreated] => 
[forceDeleting:protected] => 
)

App\User Object
(
[attributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1206
        [email] => johndoe@whoknows.com
        [password] => hashed
        [remember_token] => 
        [created_at] => 2015-09-19 09:47:16
        [updated_at] => 2015-09-19 09:47:16
        [deleted_at] => 
    )

[morphClass:protected] => 
[exists] => 1
[wasRecentlyCreated] => 
[forceDeleting:protected] => 
)
```

As you can see, there is no user_id for `Customer`, and yet Laravel has returned a `User` object.

What is more, if I manually fire the exact same `OrderSuccess` event, the above is not reproducible - it does not send the email, and it does not load a `User` object.

As I said before, this issue is happening very infrequently - there are on average about 40 orders a day via the call centre for customers with no user account, and the highlighted issue might only occur once or twice a week.

I'm not familiar enough with Laravel to know what might be the issue here - is it some form of model caching, a problem with Eloquent ORM, or some other gremlin in the system?

Any ideas appreciated - I may post this problem in the Laravel github issue tracker if it appears to be some form of bug.

**Update** Relating to some of the answers / comments put forward, I have tried to remove any potential Eloquent ORM issues, to retrieve the data manually, like so:

```
$customer = Customer::find($order->customer_id);
$user = User::find($customer->user_id);

if(!is_null($user)) {
    // send email and log actions etc
}
```

The above is *still* producing the same random results - unrelated users are being retrieved even when the customer has no `user_id` (it's NULL in this instance).

**Update 2** As the first update did not help in any way, I reverted to using the original Eloequent approach. To try another solution, I took my event code out of the event handler, and placed it in my controller - I was previously firing by OrderSuccess event using `Event::fire(new OrderSuccess ($order));`, and instead I commented this line out and just placed the event handler code in the controller method:

```
$order = Order::find($order_id);

//Event::fire(new OrderSuccess ($order));

// code from the above event handler
$order->paid = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$order->save();

if(!is_null($order->customer->user)) {

    App_log::add('customer_order_success_email_sent', 'Handlers\Events\OrderSuccessProcess\handle', $order->id, print_r($order->customer, true).PHP_EOL.print_r($order->customer->user, true));

    // email the user the order confirmation
    Mail::send('emails.order_success', ['order' => $order], function($message) use ($order)
    {
        $message->to($order->customer->user->email, $order->customer->first_name.' '.$order->customer->last_name)->subject('Order #'.$order->id.' confirmation');
    });
}
```

The above change has been on the production site for over a week now - and since that change, there has not been a single instance of the issue.

The only possible conclusion I can reach is some kind of bug in the Laravel event system, somehow corrupting the passed object. Or could something else be at play?

**Update 3**
It seems I was premature to state that moving my code outside the event fixed the issue - in fact, via my logging, in the last 2 days I can see some more incorrect order confirmation were sent out (a total of 5, after almost 3 weeks of no issues).

I noticed that the user ids that had received the rogue order confirmations appeared to be incrementing (not without gaps, but still in ascending order).

I also noticed that each of the problem orders had been paid for via cash and account credit - most are cash only. I looked further into this, and the user ids are actually the ids of the related credit transactions!

The above is the first cast iron breakthrough in trying to resolve this issue. On closer inspection, I can see that the issue is still random - there are quite a few (at least 50%) orders that have been paid via account credit for customer's with no user account, but that have not caused incorrect emails to be sent out (despite the associated credit transaction id having a user id match).

So, the problem is still random, or seemingly so. My credit redemption event is triggered like so:

```
Event::fire(new CreditRedemption( $credit, $order ));
```

The above is called just prior to my `OrderSuccess` event - as you can see, both events are passed the `$order` model object.

My `CreditRedemption` event handler looks like this:

```
public function handle(CreditRedemption $event)
{
    // make sure redemption amount is a negative value
    if($event->credit < 0) {
        $amount = $event->credit;
    }
    else {
        $amount = ($event->credit * -1);
    }

    // create the credit transaction
    $credit_transaction = New Credit_transaction();
    $credit_transaction->transaction_type = 'Credit Redemption';
    $credit_transaction->amount = $amount; // negative value
    $credit_transaction->customer_id = $event->order->customer->id;
    $credit_transaction->order_id = $event->order->id;

    // record staff member if appropriate
    if(!is_null($event->order->staff)) {
        $credit_transaction->staff_id = $event->order->staff->id;
    }

    // save transaction
    $credit_transaction->save();

    return $credit_transaction;
}
```

The `$credit_transaction->save();` is generating the id in my `credit_transactions` table that is somehow being used by Laravel to retrieve a user object. As can be seen in the above handler, I'm not updating my `$order` object at any point.

How is Laravel using (remember, still randomly, some < 50% of the time) the id of my newly created `$credit_transaciton` to populate the `$order->customer->user` model object?

Comment: can you share the migrations for User and Customer ?

Comment: Also, when you create the order, can you share that specific code ?

Comment: Are you loading anything through a db `join`? If so then if there are conflicting column names (id) it could be getting the id from the wrong table. For example, `User::join('customers', 'users.id', '=', 'customers.user_id')->first()` could fetch the correct User, but then if you investigate the $user->id you might see that it's actually the customer ID instead. You need to tell it which columns to select: `User::join(...)->select('users.*')->first()`

Comment: @codegeek - I've added the migrations info you requested. It's pretty standard stuff as you can see. The order creation code isn't really relevant - as by the time of this event being fired, it's is just retrieved from the database using `$order = Order::find($order_id);`. As I say in the question, this issue is not reproducible - I can fire the same problem event again, but the relationships are returned correctly then.

Comment: @andrewtweber - good thinking, but I am only using the Eloquent ORM relationships to build the model objects. From manual investigation there is no cross over / clashing of the user ids erroneously returned either. Plus, as above, if this was the issue it would be reproducible - I can't reproduce this issues at all, if I load the problem order and manually fire the event again, everything is fine.

Comment: ok. In your migrations, I don't see any foreign key references. You defined "user_id" in customers table but there is no foreign key reference. You need to setup foreign key reference if you want to use the belongsTo and hasOne relationships.

Comment: @codegeek - I have added a comment to your answer on this point.

Comment: @codegeek You probably **should** but you don't **need** to

Comment: Can you give code, where event fired? And try to log not only order_id, but whole order.

Comment: @EchoUA.COM I've added the code from the controller method - as you can see, all that is happening is that I am getting the $order object by its' id. I'm not sure what you're referring to with the logging - I'm currently logging the order customer and the order customer user, as well as the order id - this should be all the pertinent information.

Comment: Is there anything else in your Customer class that could be setting the user attribute?

Comment: @Trip - there is no other relationship defined in the Customer model that is based upon (or even has a table that contains) the user_id.

Comment: My question is not strictly about a relationship method/attribute. I am asking if there's *anything* else that could be setting the user attribute. As an example, you can explicitly assign an App\User model to $customer->user. Are you sure nothing like that is happening anywhere?

Comment: @BrynJ A couple questions: Does your event listener implement `ShouldQueue`? Does your event use the `SerializesModels` trait? What happens if, in your event handler, before your check for `is_null`, you add a `$order->load('customer.user');`?

Comment: @Trip - the only time a App\User is assigned to $customer->user is when that user is created. That bit doesn't form part of the flow for the order success logic, and those relationships are only accessed (read) via the $order object.

Comment: @patricus - the event uses the `SerializesModels` trait, yes (the event and handler were generated using `artisan event:generate`). The event handler  doesn't implement `ShouldQueue`. Could it be some issue with the `SerializesModels` trait?

Comment: I read some info [here](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-commands-and-handlers) that indicates that there's no need to use the `SerializesModels` trait if the handler isn't implementing `ShouldQueue`. As I said, I did use the `artisan event:generate` command to create my event and handler, so the default implementation is to use this trait, and not implement `ShouldQueue`.

Comment: There was a bug not long ago where any null foreign keys would pull out random records although it was fixed in 5.0. Not ideal, but I wonder if setting all the null foreign keys to zeros would fix this?

Comment: @Jeemusu - that's interesting, and does appear to describe the issue I'm seeing. Unfortunately, I have a system user with id zero, so I can't really implement that potential fix. Do you have a link to the github issue tracker for aforementioned bug?

Comment: When Laravel fetches a relationship it actually doesn't care what the value of the foreign key is, it just performs the query. In your case, when your `user_id` = null a query similar to this is run: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id IS NULL`

Though I don't really see how that would return a user with an id!=NULL as your logs show. Unless there's some strange case where your database has just created a user but not yet created an auto incremented id for it exactly when the query is run, and then has the id generated when the data is returned.

Comment: Relevant files to check are `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`, the `getRelationshipFromMethod` function is the one called to get a relationship, and `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php`, the `addConstraints` is the one setting the constraint for the relation, i.e the `user.id IS NULL`.

Comment: @BrynJ I think [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/1e80162e9a3a4c42a0079bd9f34e785197a66c07) was the bug I was referring to, but looking at it now I doubt thats the problem. Obviously this shouldn't be happening, but a work around might be to return to your logic from **Update 1**, with a small alteration. Try using `$customer = Customer::whereNotNull(user_id')->find($order->customer_id);` to return only a customer with a user_id. Then you could use `if (!$customer->isEmpty()) { // send email }` to check if a customer was returned and send the email.

Comment: @Jeemusu - would you like to formulate an answer based on your comments? I believe you're offering the closest I have to a solution / workaround and I have to award the bounty soon.

Comment: @Arvid - thanks for the information, this is useful and will serve me to further investigate. I'm still convinced this is some kind of issue with the SerializesModels trait though - as the bug is only apparent when the code is called from an event handler, not when it is called directly in the controller.

Comment: @BrynJ I've added the above work around as an answer. Although I'm hopeful that someone will be able to identify whats causing the issue in the first place.

Comment: @Arvid - there's a major update to my question which might shed light on the issue - if you can look, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still non the wiser. I would suggest creating a slightly more concise version of your question and posting it over at laravel.io or some other laravel forums (laracasts, etc). Either that or creating a new question, as I imagine this question isn't going to get much new traffic.

Comment: @Jeemusu - yes, I agree, as I've now identified more closely the issue. I'll work on this later and get something up.

Comment: @BrynJ have you found the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I can't help you get to the root of whats causing your issue, but I can offer a possible work around based on the logic you provided in Update 1 of your question.

## Original Logic

```
$customer = Customer::find($order->customer_id);
$user = User::find($customer->user_id);

if(!is_null($user)) {
    // send email and log actions etc
}
```

## Revised Logic

Because a customers `user_id` can be null, it may be more effective to limit the returned customers to those who have a `user_id`. This can be achieved by using the `whereNotNull()` method. We can then go on to check if a customer was returned, and if so send the email, etc.

```
$customer = Customer::whereNotNull('user_id')->find($order->customer_id); 

if (!$customer->isEmpty()) { 
    // send email and log actions etc 
}
```

By not giving the application a chance to return a customer with a null `user_id` this should hopefully solve your issue, but unfortunately it doesn't shine any light on why it is happening in the first place.

Comment: I've awarded the bounty to you, as I believe it otherwise gets automatically awarded based upon some criteria, and yours is the closest to a solution / workaround. Since moving the code out of my event handler approximately 2 weeks ago, I've not had a single instance of this issue - which just reaffirms my belief that there is some kind of Laravel bug, probably with the SerializesModels trait. I'm going to move the code back into the event handler, but remove this trait - as my event doesn't queue - and see if the issue reoccurs. If it does, I'll implement your suggestion.

Comment: I've just updated my question with a major new finding.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your migrations are defined correctly specially when compared to your Models. If you are using belongsTo and hasOne relationship, you should use foreign key references in migrations.

```
Schema::create('customers', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('telephone')->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });



Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table)
{
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->integer('payment_id')->nullable()->index();

   $table->integer('customer_id')->nullable();
   $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
   $table->integer('staff_id')->nullable()->index();
   $table->decimal('total', 10, 2);
   $table->timestamps();
   $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

Now you will need to set this column whenever an actual user exists when the customer record is being created. But you don't actually have to set this column manually. You can do this below as you are using relationships:

Step 1: Save the customer first.

```
$customer->save();
```

Step 2: Now we will set the user_id on the customer if exists. To do this, you can get the user object in $user and then just call

```
$customer->user->save($user);
```

The code above will automatically set the user_id on customers table

Then I will check if user record exists in this way below:

```
$user_exists = $order->customer()->user();

if($user_exists)
{
    //email whatever
}
```

Comment: The above is in line with how the app is constructed. However, I have never read that there is a need to actually define a foreign key for an Eloquent relationship - do you have any references to direct me to? Obviously, I'm aware of what a foreign key is and how it might be useful in terms of cascading deletes and maintaining referential integrity, at the **database** level, but not at the application level.

Comment: The referencing keys are indexed (I'm aware that's not clear from my migration code), but they're not explicitly set up as foreign keys - indeed, as we operate with soft deletes, I'm not sure there would be a direct advantage to having these set up as foreign keys?

Comment: I could be wrong of course but reading through laravel documentation, it does mention that "Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name" . If you try using my solution, does that at least work ? I really think when you are calling $order->customer->user, it is not going to work correctly based on your current setup.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, although I still read it as relating to the model, not the underlying data - I may have to look at this. At the moment, these tables use the MyISAM storage engine, which doesn't actually _support_ foreign keys. The frustrating part of this issue is that it is so hard to reproduce, and so rare in its' occurrence.

Comment: Please see my latest question update - I have tried removing Eloquent relationships from the mix completely, and I'm still randomly and rarely getting this issue.

Comment: I see. have you tried to actually debug User::find($customer->user_id) ? may be do a dd($user) to see what it returns. I have a feeling that somehow the check of is_null() could be throwing things off ? Also, the preferred way should be if($user) instead of !is_null($user).

Comment: I'm pretty sure non existent Eloquent relationships are returned as null. What I have done now is to move the exact same code block I have, out of the event - so it's just in the controller now. If the problem is solved, I'm sure this indicates a Laravel event issue, if not then the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: the change to moving my logic out of the event handler has been live a couple of days now, and there's not yet been another incorrect order confirmation go out - if this continues to be the case (I'll wait at least 10 days), then there must be some kind of issue with events in Laravel.

Comment: There has still not been an incorrect Eloquent relationship after moving the code out of an even - this is change has been live for over 1 week now. It's looking increasingly like there is some kind of random model corruption when passing a model object to an event.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your migrations have

```
->unsigned()
```

for example:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsinged()->index();
```

As mentioned in the Laravel Doc?

> Laravel also provides support for creating foreign key constraints, which are used to force referential integrity at the database level. For example, let's define a user_id column on the posts table that references the id column on a users table. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: I think this has been covered elsewhere really. There is no _need_ to have foreign keys at the database level - in fact, many database engines that Laravel supports do not support foreign keys of any type.

Comment: Adding `->unsigned()` would just increase maximum positive number of the integer field by the way (by prohibiting negative numbers and allocating all 4 bytes to positive).

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to have FK.
Eloquent can mange to build relations based on the name of the columns.

Change the name of the fields. The name of the field should match table name with suffix "_id". In the customers table user_id should be users_id. In orders customer_id should be customers_id.

You can try to pass the name of the field you want to join with:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'foreign_key', 'id');
    }
}
```

I am not very advanced user with Laravel so this might not work. I had the same issue and I solved it by renaming all models and columns to match table names (with "s").

Comment: Thanks for confirming that there is no need to actually define a foreign key. The "referencing" key is actually determined by the model name - so although we have a `users` table, it is a `User` model, hence the key is named `user_id`. Here is a reference for this - http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one. I should add that relationships are not an issue in the main - just in this very infrequent and random issue.

Comment: You are right that should not be the issue in your case. I am sorry I was not able to help.

Comment: Although you don't need to define foreign keys, for large applications it helps as foreign keys add indexes that speed up searching.

Comment: @Pistachio - the linking keys are all indexed, they just don't have the foreign key restraint. Performance is thus equivalent (and perhaps higher, as no cascading actions will ever take place)

Answer (score 0):

your `user_id` field in customers table should be nullable.

```
$table->integer('user_id')->index()->nullable();
```

Comment: This is actually set to nullable, i'll update my question - I copied the initial migration, but there were some further ones that added this, amongst other changes